# How to collect data from more than two localhost to one main server in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, version-control, controls, version

I want to know that is it possible to crate a web site on different local servers and after that collect all data to another local server for final version control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible dude, please follow steps.

Step 1:- download whole data base in local server

step 2:- open that file in notepad and find current local site url and
 Replace to all new site url.

Step 3:- import that database file to new server

Step4:- go to word press admin site and change permalink.

Ex:- old site utl is www.oldsite.com 
     new site is   www.newsite.com
     1:- download to old site database
     2:- open on notepad Replace all site url  www.oldsite.com to www.newsite.com and site that file
     3:- import that file to new local database 
     4) go to wordpress admin and change permalink setting

enjoy i hope it's working for you. :)

Comment: Hello Mithun, We are creating same website on three different machines,  and now I want to collect work of each person to one machine and then upload to server

Comment: ohh.. so only one option. you have to crate github a/c and create user.

it's same work SVN. more info visit https://github.com/

Comment: ohh.. so only one option. you have to crate github a/c and create user.